# Updating Rails 4.2 to 5.0.0 & sqlite3 gem will not load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rails-4-upgrade

When running `rails server`, I load this warning:

`` Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). ``

Yet my gemfile has the gem

```
 group :development do
   gem 'sqlite3'
```

What is causing this error?

Using instructions for rails update from here https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-4-2-to-rails-5-0

Comment: Deleted gem sqlite3 ( v 1.4.0 ) and installed it with version 1.3.13 & it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gem cleanup sqlite3
```

And

```
bundle install
```

to let Rails choose right version of `sqlite3`

Answer (score 2):

Deleted gem sqlite3 ( v 1.4.0 ) and installed it with version 1.3.13 & it worked

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem in AWS cloud9 environment. You need to change your gemfile to read gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6' then run bundle update. got this from "[can't activate sqlite3 (~> 1.3.6), already activated sqlite3-1.4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54527277)"